# How to add press effect or selector indicator to astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip?

Tags: android, pagerslidingtabstrip

I used astuetz library and implemented PagerSlidingTabStrip for my android application, it's working find. Now I want to change pressing effect, I tried:

```
android:background="@drawable/tab_selecor"
```

Code for tab selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/darkGreen" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/darkGreen" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/green" />
</selector>
```

The press colour suppose to be changed to dark green but as you see it does not change, it still looks like this even if I use another colour like red, yellow, .... .

[image]
[image]

Comment: You are looking for press effect or selector indicator

Comment: @Fahim: Yes, exactly. Shall I change the title of my question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of [setIndicatorColor()](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/blob/master/library/src/com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip.java) for  setting the color of indicator and [setIndicatorHeight()](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/blob/master/library/src/com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip.java) for setting the height

And make use of setTabBackground() method to set the background to tab

Use this drawable for tab background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <!-- Active tab --> 
<item
 android:state_selected="true"
 android:state_focused="false" 
    android:state_pressed="false"
 android:drawable="@color/red" /> <!-- Inactive tab --> 
<item
 android:state_selected="false"
 android:state_focused="false" 
    android:state_pressed="false"
 android:drawable="@android:color/black" />
 <!-- Pressed tab --> 
<item
 android:state_pressed="true"
 android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" /> 
<!-- Selected tab (using d-pad) -->
 <item
 android:state_focused="true"
 android:state_selected="true" 
    android:state_pressed="false"
 android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
 </selector>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not my purpose. I know about indicator colors, I'm trying another thing.

Comment: Thanks that didn't worked too. the problem was not within my selector or your selector. I changed `android:background="@drawable/tab_selecor"` ---> `    `app:pstsTabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"`

Comment: Yes that what I mentioned in my answer the tab background, for gt to mention you setTabBackground() method

Comment: Now `setIndicator` is not working after setting background colour of the tab using `app:pstsTabBackground`.  Strange behaviour!!

Comment: Can you try setting from code behind using setTabBackground()

Comment: if the above doesn't work, then you can directly update the library drawable file https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/blob/master/library/res/drawable/background_tab.xml... let me know what works

Comment: That doesn't work too, I changed the res inside the library too. However, I decided to remove the effect `android:color/transparent`